# Number guessing game

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to make a number guessing game. It has a set of numbers and it is supposed to count and display the number of times you have guessed once you guess the correct number.

Currently the program runs the first 2 steps then just stops please help to solve this

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  
import java.util.Scanner;
//Scott Timmerman TwentyQuestions

public class TwentyQuestions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 500000;
        int numberoftries = 0; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scott Timmerman TwentyQuestions");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        boolean win = false;
        while (win == false) {

            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 and 1,000,000" );
            guess = input.nextInt(); 
            numberoftries++; 
            if(guess == number) {
                win = true;
            }
            else if(guess > number){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your guess " + guess + " was greater then the number");

            }
            else if (guess < number){ 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your guess " + guess + " was less then the number");

            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you lost!\n the number was " + number );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you won!" + numberoftries + " tries");

        }


}
    `
```

Comment: 'the program runs the first 2 steps then just stops' - what does this mean?  What steps?  Stops with an error?  Just exits?

Comment: Please don't compare booleans like that. Use `while(!win)` or `while(win)` for the opposite.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly happens when your program runs and what doesn't?

Comment: the first  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scott Timmerman TwentyQuestions"); pops up then i click ok. then the next  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 and 1,000,000" ); pops up and i enter a number click ok then nothing happens after that

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you want the user to enter the next guess in the dialog box rather than at the console. If that's the case then you need to use the return value from `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`. The return value is then the text that the user entered before clicking the `ok` button. You will need to covert this to an integer using something like `Integer.parseUnsignedInt` which includes handling `NumberFormatException` (in case they type in something that isn't a number).

So something like:

```
try {
    String guessText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your next guess");
    int guess = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(guessText);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It stops because the program wait till you provide the value on the console not on the Java Dialogue.
Switch to console and write there for example 500 and hit enter.
This is the problem: Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: ahh i see. how do i make it work with java dialogue?

Comment: String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 and 1,000,000");guess = Integer.valueOf(answer);